# Why is there a quotation mark on the operators like 'mod'?

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and I probably have some really dumb questions (so sorry about that).

I was reading some tutorials for starters and noticed that there are expressions like this:

```
removeNonUppercase st = [ c | c <- st, c `elem` ['A'..'Z']]

ghci> [ x | x <- [50..100], x `mod` 7 == 3]
```

I know what `mod` and `elem` means but why do they have a quotation mark on them?

Huge thanks!

Comment: surrounding a function with backticks makes it act like an infix operator

Comment: For instance, ``x `mod` 7`` is the same as `mod x 7`

Comment: to be more precise ``(x `mod` 7)`` is the same as `(mod x 7)`, while ``(x y `mod` z 7)`` is `mod (x y) (z 7)`.